# Swing MVC, display in JList after deserialization

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, serialization

I have a problem with the following code.
I'm making an application that allows me to create a few persons, display in the JList Swing element, serialize, deserialize and manipulate the person objects.

The problem is this: I have 2 JFrameForm classes, the main one that contains the JList and the "Add" button and the second JFrameForm class that gets visible once I press on that "Add" button from the first class. The second JFrameForm class called adaugaPers.java has a couple of labels and textfields from which the user takes the data to create the Person object. Later, those person objects are being added to the model and the model notifies the JList which is part of the class that doesn't have any references to the model. The class having references to the model is the adaugaPers.java class and then I get a reference to the model in order to set the model for the JList. The code will make the things clearer but this is the problem. After I've added a few persons, then I serialize the object(save the object) then I deserialize and the JList gets updated, good so far. But then, when I try to add a new Person it adds that new Person to a brand new LinkedList with an initial size of 0. So, for every call of the app I get a new LinkedList and not the LinkedList before the serialization and even deserialization process. Here's the code!!

MainGui.java: This is the class containing the JList Swing element and doesn't have a dirrect reference to the model object

```
public class MainGui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 JFileChooser browser;
 adaugaPers obiect;
 model model;


public MainGui() {
    initComponents();
    obiect=new adaugaPers();
    model=obiect.getModel();
    lista.setModel(model);

}
private void openDbActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    File mainFile=new File("C:\\Users\\Andrei\\Desktop\\TEST");
    browser=new JFileChooser(mainFile);

    if(browser.showOpenDialog(this)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        try {
            File fisier=new   File("C:\\Users\\Andrei\\Desktop\\TEST\\serializare");
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fisier);
            try {
                ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);

                try {
                    model=(model)ois.readObject();
                    // System.out.println(model.listaPersoane.get(2));
                    lista.setModel(model);
                    System.out.print("Linked List's version: ");
                    System.out.println(model.lista);
                    System.out.print("Linked List's size after deserialization: ");
                    System.out.println(model.lista.size());

                    // System.out.println(model.listaPersoane.size());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}                                      

private void saveDbActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    File mainFile=new File("C:\\Users\\Andrei\\Desktop\\TEST");

    browser=new JFileChooser(mainFile);

    if(browser.showSaveDialog(this)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        try {
            File fisier=new File("C:\\Users\\Andrei\\Desktop\\TEST\\serializare");
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fisier);
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(model);
                oos.close();
                //System.out.println("S-a salvat obiectul!"+model);
                //System.out.println(model.listaPersoane.size());

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

} 

public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            MainGui guiMain=new MainGui();
            guiMain.setVisible(true);
            guiMain.setTitle("The Gui in which I try to display something!!");
        }
    });
}
```

adaugaPers.java  This is the class that has a direct refference to the model and send it to the mainClass. Through it, the linkedlist from the model gets populated!

```
public class adaugaPers extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private  model m=new model();//camp al clasei

model getModel()
{
    return m;
}

public adaugaPers() {
    initComponents();
    // there is no Jlist in this class to set the model fo
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String nume=tNume.getText();
    Persoana p=new Persoana(nume);
    m.adaugaPers(p);
    System.out.println(m);

} 

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lNume;
private javax.swing.JTextField tNume;
```

model.java This is the class containing the linkedList object, the "M" from MVC

```
public class model extends AbstractListModel {

List lista=new LinkedList();

@Override
public int getSize() {

    return lista.size();

}

@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return lista.get(index);

}

public void adaugaPers(Persoana p)
{
    //System.out.println(lista);
    lista.add(p);
    fireContentsChanged(this, 0, lista.size());
    System.out.println(lista.size());//just for testing
}
}
```

Persoana.java

```
class Persoana implements Serializable{

private String nume;

public Persoana(String nume)
{
    this.nume=nume;
}

public String getNume()
{
    return nume;
}
public String toString()
{
    return nume;
}

}
```

I really need to figure out where the problem is. It seems at different calls of the app, I don't know how to refer to the linkedlist before serialization so it creates a new linkedlist...List lista=new LinkedList();